# My app seems to automatically log in and launch straight into the third activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am creating an app in Android studio. I have connected it to google fire base and I have added myself successfully through my app as user. But it seems like after I signed in the app is launching directly into the third activity instead of starting from the first activity. I would like it to start from the first Activity all the time. What have I missed or done that is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare your first activity as the launcher activity in your manifest file like this :

```
    <activity android:name=".YourFirstActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

When an app is launched, Android system will first read the manifest file and launch the activity with the above launcher tag.

Also you should note if you are launching your third activity once user signin is successful. Check for any code like this in your first activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourFirstActivity.this, YouThirdActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

If this is the case android will launch your third activity once the login process is successful every time you launch your app.

Comment: Yes that that is the code I am using to launch third activity. will only declaring my first activity as the launcher activity be enough or do I need to change the code I am using to launch third activity?

Comment: I have just checked the manifest and that declaration is already there. So what is the best code to launch activity 3 so that app does not start from activity 3?

Comment: Everytime you launch the app, the first activity will be called as declared in the manifest. In first activity, system will check if the user is already logged in. If user is loggedin previously, it will automatically launch the third activity as declared in Intent. So if you logout and try again, you will be shown first activity. If you want to show the login screen (first activity here) and need to make your users login everytime they launch the app, just remove "Intent intent = new Intent(YourFirstActivity.this, YouThirdActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);" from the code.

Comment: firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPassword).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
          @Override
          public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

Comment: if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(LogIn.this, "LOG IN SUCCESSFUL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(LogIn.this,Options.class));

Comment: I don't know how to post my code here but the two above is how my code looks like in that respect

Comment: and the other bit as follows:

Comment: FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if(user !=null){
            finish();
           startActivity(new Intent(LogIn.this,Options.class));
        }

Comment: options is my third activity

Comment: Even when I click log out from the third activity it is still bringing me back to third activity.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have removed bit of code, the last bit I shared, that was causing that and its okay now.

Comment: glad that helped :)